# Micro optimization of apk files

Tags: android, optimization

I'm wondering which useless meta files I can strip out of apk files. I'm excluding currently:

```
android {
    // ...
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE*'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE*'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'
        exclude 'META-INF/*.version'
        exclude 'kotlin/**'
    }
}
```

However I'm not really sure if it is safe to delete all the `.kotlin_module` and `.version` files. There are also tons of `.properties` files where I assume that most of them are useless  too.

Is there a simple way to identify which files are really useless (and just contain e.g. version information, but no important configuration)?

I also noticed that some more important files contain comments, is there a plugin to strip the comments out? On the client side those comments are totally useless.

I'm aware that those are micro optimizations, but if you strip out 500kb for 1M users that begins to matter.

Comment: worth note that `LICENCE` files may be obligatory, some of 3rd party lib licences are "forcing" to keep these files (and also mentioning about lib usage in some credentials of app)

Comment: @snachmsm do you have an example? I never observed that yet. However I always credit the authors of libs, but I never use the license files to display them. Most times I just link to the license files on the web. TBH I don't think that anyone actually cares about the license text itself just the licensing.